# Add subviews according To UITableViewCell CGRect

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I'm trying to add subviews to a view according to the cell of the tableview .. i've done this code already

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VerseCell *cell = (VerseCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    rowSelected = indexPath.row;

    CGRect  cellRect = cell.frame;

    UIView *cellView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x+4, cellRect.origin.y+15, cellRect.size.width-20, 70)];

  UIImageView* background =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoritePanelBackground"]];
    background.frame =CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x+4, cellRect.origin.y+15, cellRect.size.width-20, 70);
    [cellView addSubview:background];
    [cellView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] ];
    UIButton * favoritsB = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cellRect.origin.x+10, cellRect.origin.y+15, 60, 40)];
    [favoritsB setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MofadalatNormalIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [favoritsB setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MofadalatTappedIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  [favoritsB addTarget:self action:@selector(favorite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cellView addSubview:favoritsB];

    cellView=nil;

}
```

the problem is .. that this code work as expected in the first row only.. and when click on next cell it shows the main UIVIew (which i've mark with red background) in the expected position while the sub views of it is going really far down... so what i'm doing wrong here.. and is there another approach for what i'm doing if that will not work?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to add these view? Inside the table view cell? If so, you never add cellView as a subview of cell. IF that's what you're trying to do, add this line just above cellView = nil:

[cell addSubview:cellView];

Comment: actually i'm adding it as subview for the self.view not the table itself